# Creating a countdown-timer(NSTimer) with milliseconds but it doesn't count down correctly

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, countdown

I'm quite new to Xcode (swift), and in short I'm trying to make a countdown timer that counts down with seconds and decimals.

It does countdown as it should but, for example, when I count down from 13 seconds, it really takes 23 seconds when I manually time it. 
It's probably a simple solution, but I have tried many things and can't figure out how to fix it.

Here's my code:

```
 import UIKit

var timer = NSTimer()

var seconds = 13

var milliseconds = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        Label.text = "\(seconds).\(milliseconds)"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func Button(sender: AnyObject) {

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.001, target: self, selector: Selector("countDownfunction"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }


    func countDownfunction() {

        Label.text = "\(seconds).\(milliseconds)"

        if milliseconds == 0 {

            seconds -= 1
            milliseconds = 100
        } else {
            milliseconds -= 1
        }

    }

}
```

EDIT: New code still haven't figured it out but on the right way i think, and how can I substract/compare two strings like i did at: Label.text = (countdownSeconds - elapsedTime)
It gives me an error that I can't '-' two strings I don't know how to compare the two seconds. Thank you

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

var startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

var elapsedTime = String()

var differenceTime = String()

var countdownSeconds = String()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    countdownSeconds = String(10)

    startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("countDownUpdateMethod"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



}

func countDownUpdateMethod(){

    currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    elapsedTime = String(currentTime - startTime )



    Label.text = (countdownSeconds - elapsedTime)



}



}
```

Comment: `NSTimer` is not high enough resolution for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring the time that it actually takes to schedule and perform the call to `countDownfunction`.  `NSTimer` is not going to call you back in precisely 100 msec, because the phone is doing other things.  It's simply not going to be that accurate. Also, the `countDownfunction` call itself is going to take time and you're not accounting for that.

You should fix this by recording the start time and checking the current time inside `countDownfunction`, then subtracting the two to set your label.  This way you compensate for any delays in handling the timer.

You can use `NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()` to get the current time.

Comment: @Josh Please accept the answer if you're happy, thanks.

Comment: Yes I will, I forgot, but i still haven't figured it out completely. the var Seconds is counting down from 13 how would I do then when i compare that with NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() to make sure its the correct time?

Comment: I still haven't figured out yet I updated post with new code. @EwanMellor

Comment: Don't try and subtract strings.  Have all your variables declared as NSTimeInterval (which is a floating point number in seconds).  Do all the math with numbers.  Only convert to a string when it comes to display, like Label.text = String(amountOfTimeLeft).

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that you set milliseconds to 100, not to 1000?

So your timer gets called about 1300 times in 23 seconds. That sounds about right. What makes you think counting down 1000 times per second is a good idea? People can't see that.

If you read the documentation of NSTimer, repeating timers will try to trigger at the expected time (so they trigger not X seconds after the last trigger, but they try to trigger X, 2X, 3X, 4X seconds after the timer was started), but if a timer isn't triggered at all within the given time, that trigger is dropped. So in 23 seconds your timer didn't trigger 23,000 times, but 1300 times, as one would expect. You can't update the screen 1,000 times per second. If you could, nobody would be able to see it.

Run your timer at a reasonable rate, not more than 30 times per second, and calculate what the time is. Not based on a count down, but based on the actual time.

Comment: Yeah gnasher you are right, I didn't notice It was 100 milliseconds my mistake. But from what I've heard NSTimer isn't very accurate so I wan't to learn about getting it more accurate by using NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate(). I did update post with new code do you have time to check it out? Thank you. @gnasher729